# every() es6 for nested array is not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I expect `true` for below usage of `every` but it wasn't, what's wrong with my logic?

```
const isAllChecked = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "checked": true,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "checked": true,
        "nested": [
            {
                "id": "2.1",
                "checked": true,
            },
            {
                "id": "2.2",
                "checked": true,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "checked": true,
    },
].every(
    (o) =>
      o.checked &&
      o.nested?.every((o) => o.checked)
  )
```

What I wanted: if any of the level 1 `checked` or nested `checked` is `false` then `isAllChecked` is `false`, but if non of the `checked` property in level 1 or nested is `false`, `isAllChecked` should return true.

Comment: the issue is `o.nested?` is falsy if there is no nested

Comment: `.every(o1 => o1.checked && (o1?.nested?.every(o2 => o2.checked) ?? true));` ---> should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional chaining will evaluate to `undefined` if the chain fails, so for the second iteration

```
(o) =>
  o.checked &&
  o.nested?.every((o) => o.checked)
```

will evaluate to

```
(o) =>
  true
  undefined
```

You probably wanted

```
(o) =>
  o.checked &&
  (!o.nested || o.nested.every((o) => o.checked))
```

or

```
(o) =>
  o.checked &&
  (o.nested || []).every(o => o.checked)
```

```js
const isAllChecked = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "checked": true,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "checked": true,
        "nested": [
            {
                "id": "2.1",
                "checked": true,
            },
            {
                "id": "2.2",
                "checked": true,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "checked": true,
    },
].every(
    (o) =>
      o.checked &&
      (o.nested || []).every((o) => o.checked)
  )
console.log(isAllChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a `nested` property, `o.nested?` will evaluate to a *falsy* value.

You could use a combination of [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const isAllChecked = [{
    "id": "1",
    "checked": true,
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "checked": true,
    "nested": [{
        "id": "2.1",
        "checked": true,
      },
      {
        "id": "2.2",
        "checked": true,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "checked": true,
  },
].every((o) => o.checked && !o.nested?.some((o) => !o.checked));

console.log(isAllChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

If an item doesn't contain the nested property then `o.nested?.every((o) => o.checked)` will evaluate to `false`, hence the `every` method would also return `false`.

You can instead use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the checking the items inside the `nested` array.

```js
const isAllChecked = [
  { id: "1", checked: true },
  {
    id: "2",
    checked: true,
    nested: [
      { id: "2.1", checked: true },
      { id: "2.2", checked: true },
    ],
  },
  { id: "3", checked: true },
].every((o) => o.checked && !o.nested?.some((o) => !o.checked));

console.log(isAllChecked);
```